# Could not build application for the simulator

Tags: android, ios, flutter, flutter-dependencies, flutter-web

```
Launching lib/main.dart on iPhone 11 in debug mode...
 
Running pod install...                                             17.9s
Running Xcode build...                                                  
                                                   
 └─Compiling, linking and signing...                        14.2s
Xcode build done.                                           185.2s
Failed to build iOS app
Error output from Xcode build:
↳
    2020-10-02 15:52:17.790 XCBBuildService[92468:463272] Failed to remove:
    /Users/gopichand/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-dfeoyynhjaxtdubsjwlrommeqqhn/Build/Interm
    ediates.noindex/XCBuildData/9bd14026a93f0e29dacb54f223c51718-manifest.xcbuild:
    unlink(/Users/gopichand/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-dfeoyynhjaxtdubsjwlrommeqqhn/Build
    /Intermediates.noindex/XCBuildData/9bd14026a93f0e29dacb54f223c51718-manifest.xcbuild): No such file
    or directory (2)
    2020-10-02 15:52:18.047 XCBBuildService[92468:463272] Failed to remove:
    /Users/gopichand/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-dfeoyynhjaxtdubsjwlrommeqqhn/Build/Interm
    ediates.noindex/XCBuildData/9bd14026a93f0e29dacb54f223c51718-desc.xcbuild:
    unlink(/Users/gopichand/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-dfeoyynhjaxtdubsjwlrommeqqhn/Build
    /Intermediates.noindex/XCBuildData/9bd14026a93f0e29dacb54f223c51718-desc.xcbuild): No such file or
    directory (2)
    2020-10-02 15:52:37.865 xcodebuild[92464:463031] [MT] iPhoneConnect: <DVTiOSDevice
    (0x7fe0f33c4a10), Gopichand’s iPhone, iPhone, 14.0.1 (18A393),
    2daa4ce564d608bd832f0403d6f1a9fbc473c1bf> == Underlying device preparation errors ==
    2020-10-02 15:52:37.866 xcodebuild[92464:463031] [MT] iPhoneConnect: Failed
    _shouldMakeReadyForDevelopment check even though device is not locked by passcode.
    Domain: com.apple.platform.iphoneos
    Code: 5
    Failure Reason: allowsSecureServices: 1. isConnected: 0. Platform:
    <DVTPlatform:0x7fe0ee426720:'com.apple.platform.iphoneos':<DVTFilePath:0x7fe0ee426570:'/Applications/
    Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform'>>. DTDKDeviceIdentifierIsIDID: 0
    User Info: {
        DVTDeviceDescription = "\Ud83d\Udcf1<DVTiOSDevice (0x7fe0f33c4a10), Gopichand\U2019s iPhone,
        iPhone, 14.0.1 (18A393), 2daa4ce564d608bd832f0403d6f1a9fbc473c1bf>";
    }
    --
    2020-10-02 15:52:37.866 xcodebuild[92464:463031] [MT] iPhoneConnect: <DVTiOSDevice
    (0x7fe0f33c4a10), Gopichand’s iPhone, iPhone, 14.0.1 (18A393),
    2daa4ce564d608bd832f0403d6f1a9fbc473c1bf> == END: Underlying device preparation errors ==
    ** BUILD FAILED **
```

Xcode's output:

```
↳
    2020-10-02 15:55:08.619 ibtoold[96891:470853] DEBUG: Added to environment: {
        TMPDIR = "/var/folders/ff/r5npj56s077bhcklrn7rxdhh0000gn/T/2274EF74-2261-4AF6-B812-D36B73551C62";
    }
    /* com.apple.actool.document.warnings */
    /Users/gopichand/Downloads/srm-updatedlogo-getstarted/ios/Runner/Assets.xcassets:./AppIcon.appiconset
    : warning: A 76x76@2x app icon is required for iPad apps targeting iOS 7.0 and later
    /Users/gopichand/Downloads/srm-updatedlogo-getstarted/ios/Runner/Assets.xcassets:./AppIcon.appiconset
    : warning: A 83.5x83.5@2x app icon is required for iPad apps targeting iOS 9.0 and later
    /* com.apple.actool.document.notices */
    /Users/gopichand/Downloads/srm-updatedlogo-getstarted/ios/Runner/Assets.xcassets:./AppIcon.appiconset
    /[][iphone][57x57][][][1x][][]: notice: 57x57 app icons only apply to iPhone apps targeting releases
    of iOS prior to 7.0
    /Users/gopichand/Downloads/srm-updatedlogo-getstarted/ios/Runner/Assets.xcassets:./AppIcon.appiconset
    /[][iphone][57x57][][][2x][][]: notice: 57x57@2x app icons only apply to iPhone apps targeting
    releases of iOS prior to 7.0
    /* com.apple.actool.compilation-results */
    /Users/gopichand/Downloads/srm-updatedlogo-getstarted/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/Runner.app/AppI
    con60x60@2x.png
    /Users/gopichand/Downloads/srm-updatedlogo-getstarted/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/Runner.app/Asse
    ts.car
    /Users/gopichand/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-dfeoyynhjaxtdubsjwlrommeqqhn/Build/Interm
    ediates.noindex/Runner.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Runner.build/assetcatalog_generated_info.plist

    /Users/gopichand/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-dfeoyynhjaxtdubsjwlrommeqqhn/Build/Interm
    ediates.noindex/Runner.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Runner.build/Script-77954228A945D3139096F339.sh:
    line 2: /Users/gopichand/Downloads/srm-updatedlogo-getstarted/ios/Pods/Target Support
    Files/Pods-Runner/Pods-Runner-frameworks.sh: Permission denied
    Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code
    note: Using new build system
    note: Building targets in parallel
    note: Planning build
    note: Constructing build description
    warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the
    range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.0.99. (in target 'GTMSessionFetcher' from
    project 'Pods')
    warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the
    range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.0.99. (in target 'FirebaseCore' from
    project 'Pods')
    warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the
    range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.0.99. (in target 'FirebaseCoreDiagnostics'
    from project 'Pods')
    warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the
    range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.0.99. (in target 'FirebaseAuth' from
    project 'Pods')
    warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the
    range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.0.99. (in target 'FirebaseFirestore' from
    project 'Pods')
    warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the
    range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.0.99. (in target 'nanopb' from project
    'Pods')
    warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the
    range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.0.99. (in target 'leveldb-library' from
    project 'Pods')
    warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the
    range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.0.99. (in target 'gRPC-Core' from project
    'Pods')
    warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the
    range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.0.99. (in target 'gRPC-C++' from project
    'Pods')
    warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the
    range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.0.99. (in target
    'gRPC-C++-gRPCCertificates-Cpp' from project 'Pods')
    warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the
    range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.0.99. (in target 'fluttertoast' from
    project 'Pods')
    warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the
    range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.0.99. (in target 'firebase_core' from
    project 'Pods')
    warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the
    range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.0.99. (in target 'firebase_auth' from
    project 'Pods')
    warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the
    range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.0.99. (in target 'cloud_firestore' from
    project 'Pods')
    warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the
    range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.0.99. (in target 'abseil' from project
    'Pods')
    warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the
    range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.0.99. (in target 'Toast' from project
    'Pods')
    warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the
    range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.0.99. (in target 'PromisesObjC' from
    project 'Pods')
    warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the
    range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.0.99. (in target 'GoogleDataTransport'
    from project 'Pods')
    warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the
    range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.0.99. (in target 'GoogleUtilities' from
    project 'Pods')
    warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the
    range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.0.99. (in target 'BoringSSL-GRPC' from
    project 'Pods')
    warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the
    range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.0.99. (in target 'FirebaseAuthInterop'
    from project 'Pods')
    warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the
    range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.0.99. (in target 'Flutter' from project
    'Pods')
    warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the
    range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.0.99. (in target 'Firebase' from project
    'Pods')
    warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the
    range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.0.99. (in target
    'FirebaseCoreDiagnosticsInterop' from project 'Pods')

Could not build the application for the simulator.
Error launching application on iPhone 11.
```

and i have done everything from flutter pub get, done pod install, pod update, flutter clean and flutter run
but the error is coming and
i have latest versions of flutter, dart, cocoapods

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to Podfile which is in the iOS directory and change the ios version

```
# Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
# platform :ios, '9.0' // you have to change this because firebase required 9 to 14

# CocoaPods analytics sends network stats synchronously affecting flutter build latency.
ENV['COCOAPODS_DISABLE_STATS'] = 'true'
```

Comment: Accept my answer if it is useful for you.